# Error message in python-mysql cursor: 1054 unknown column "x" in 'field list'

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-error-1054

This is my first post! I *also* just started programming, so please bear with me!

I am trying to load a bunch of .csv files into a database, in order to later perform various reports on the data. I started off by creating a few tables in mysql with matching field names and data types to what will be loaded into the tables. I am manipulating the filename (in order to parse out the date to use as a field in my table) and cleaning up the data with python.

So my problem right now (haha...) is that I get this error message when I attempt the 'Insert Into' query to mysql.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
File "C:\Program Files\Python\load_domains2.py", line 80, in <module>  
cur.execute(sql)
File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 166, in execute
self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 35, in defaulterrorhandler
raise errorclass, errorvalue
OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'a1200e.com' in 'field list'")
```

'a1200e.com' refers to a specific domain name I'm inserting into that column. My query is as follows:

```
sql="""INSERT INTO temporary_load
    (domain_name, session_count, search_count, click_count,
    revenue, revenue_per_min, cost_per_click, traffic_date)
    VALUES (%s, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %s)""" %(cell[0],
                                                int(cell[1]),
                                                int(cell[2].replace (",","")),
                                                int(cell[3].replace(",","")),
                                                float(cell[4].replace("$","")),
                                                float(cell[5].replace("$","")),
                                                float(cell[6].replace("$","")),
                                                parsed_date)

    cur.execute(sql)
```

I am very new at all this, so I'm sure my code isn't at all efficient, but I just wanted to lay everything out so it's clear to me. What I don't understand is that I have ensured my table has correctly defined data types (corresponding to those in my query). Is there something I'm missing? I've been trying to work this out for a while, and don't know what could be wrong :/

Thanks so much!!!
Val

Answer (score 2):

[**Thomas**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2226258/error-message-in-python-mysql-cursor-1054-unknown-column-x-in-field-list/2226296#2226296) is, as usual, absolutely correct: feel free to let MySQLdb handle the quoting issues.

In addition to that recommendation:

1. The **[csv module](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html)** is your friend.
2. MySQLdb uses the "format" parameter style as detailed in [**PEP 249**](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/).
   What does that mean for you?
   All parameters, whatever **[type](http://docs.python.org/library/types.html)**, should be passed to MySQLdb as strings (like this `%s`).  MySQLdb will make sure that the values are properly converted to SQL literals.
   By the way, MySQLdb has some **[good documentation](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html)**.
3. Feel free to include more detail about your source data.  That may make diagnosing the problem easier.

Here's one way to insert values to a MySQL database from a .csv file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import csv
import MySQLdb
import os

def main():
    db = MySQLdb.connect(db="mydb",passwd="mypasswd",) # connection string

    filename = 'data.csv'
    f = open(filename, "rb") # open your csv file
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    # assuming the first line of your csv file has column names
    col_names = reader.next() # first line of .csv file
    reader = csv.DictReader(f, col_names) # apply column names to row values

    to_db = [] # this list holds values you will insert to db
    for row in reader: # loop over remaining lines in .csv file
        to_db.append((row['col1'],row['col2']))
    # or if you prefer one-liners
    #to_db = [(row['col1'],row['col2']) for row in reader]
    f.close() # we're done with the file now

    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.executemany('''INSERT INTO mytable (col1,col2) 
                    VALUES (%s, %s)''', to_db) # note the two arguments
    cursor.close()
    db.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be using DB-API quoting instead of including the data in the SQL query directly:

```
sql = """INSERT INTO temporary_load
    (domain_name, session_count, search_count, click_count,
    revenue, revenue_per_min, cost_per_click, traffic_date)
    VALUES (%s, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %s)"""
args = (cell[0],
        int(cell[1]),
        int(cell[2].replace (",","")),
        int(cell[3].replace(",","")),
        float(cell[4].replace("$","")),
        float(cell[5].replace("$","")),
        float(cell[6].replace("$","")),
        parsed_date)
cur.execute(sql, args)
```

This makes the DB-API module quote the values appropriately, and resolves a whole host of issues that you might get when doing it by hand (and usually incorrectly.)

Comment: ok thanks. For some reason, my comment to another person who responded is gone...maybe you can help me?

Basically, now I need to also get rid of the commas for the float types...but I am already replacing the dollar signs. How can I replace two types of symbols for one variable?

Comment: @DalivDali, if you ask one question per question you'll get answers -- but answering "half a question" since you're asking two questions in a single question and one already got answered makes little sense (indeed it makes little sense for you to ask 2 questions in one!!!).